# Angular2 access a select event change within the component

Tags: select, typescript, angular

Working with Angular2s forms and trying to figure out the process of handling events with selects. I have an object Heros that is stored in the options. What I want to do is that when I hero is selected, trigger an event to the parent component that will do something with the results. However, I can't find a concrete example of being able to receive an event when the selection has changed (ie a new hero in the list as been selected).

```
interface Hero {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template:`
  <h1>{{title}}</h1>
  <form>
    <select>
        <option *ngFor="#hero of heros "
                [value]="hero">
            {{hero .name}}
        </option>
    </select>
  </form>
`
})
   export class AppComponent {
   @Input() heros:Observable<Hero>
   @Output("selectedHeroChange") selectedHeroChange:EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter

   onHeroChange(hero:Hero){
      this.selectedHeroChange._next(hero);
   }    
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Mabe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31177984/selects-events-in-angular2

Comment: `this.selectedHeroChange.emit(hero);`

Comment: @EricMartinez The issues is that it never makes to go the onHeroChange function at all, cause I am unsure of how/when to call it.

Answer (score 12):

Execute code on select change and use an `id` property or `index` as value`:

```dart
<select (change)="onHeroChange($event)">
    <option *ngFor="#hero of heros; #i=index"
  [value]="hero.id">
      <!-- [value]="i" -->
        {{hero.name}}
    </option>
</select>
```

get the selected value from the event

```dart
onHeroChange(event:Event):void {
  Hero hero = heros.firstWhere(
      (Hero hero) => hero.id == (event.target as SelectElement).value);
  // Hero hero = heros[int.parse((event.target as SelectElement).value)];
  selectedHero = hero;
  selectedHeroChange.add(hero);
}
```

See also https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4843#issuecomment-170147058

See also [Binding select element to object in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35945001/binding-select-element-to-object-in-angular-2)

Comment: I was attempting to do this, but what is happening is that the [value]="hero" seems to be converted via toString instead of storing the actual object. To get this solution to work, I would have to have [value]="hero.id" and then I'd need to iterate through my list of for the onchange event and then return.... which seems like a gap (this functionality worked within KO)

Comment: For TS your function would look like this: `onheroChange(event: Event): void { ... }`

Comment: Thanks for the hint! Just a little more than a year but feels like ages ago :D

Comment: That edit was quick! I've been trying to trigger an event when switching tabs in a md-tab-group. It does seem to have a selectChange-event but I don't know how to define it. Your solution was worth a shot, thanks.

Comment: That seems promissing but I'm not quite sure how to implement that. I'm fairly new to Angular 2 and I've not used @Output yet. Could we take this to chat or should I ask a new StackOverflow question?

Comment: You shouldn't need to implement an output, the `<md-tab-group>` has that already. You should just need to add an expression that you want to have executed on tab-change where I put `...`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139465/discussion-between-wouter-vanherck-and-gunter-zochbauer).

Comment: Correction to my (deleted) comment above:
What about <md-tab-group (selectedIndexChange)="..." https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/02f4bc3730ad12a13fa5ce3572bb07fe1d1c8753/src/lib/tabs/tab-group.ts#L83

Answer (score 6):

Seem there is a gap in ng2 that select cannot handle objects. Here is a work round for now.

[How to use select/option/NgFor on an array of objects in Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33181936/how-to-use-select-option-ngfor-on-an-array-of-objects-in-angular2)

Answer (score 2):

You get the object from a select by using

```
[ngValue]="hero"
```

instead of

```
[value]="hero".
```