# Angular 2: How to get the selected value from different options of a form?

Tags: forms, html-select, angular, angular-ngmodel, angular2-forms

I would like to use a `<select>` in a form to let the user being able to update values among different `<option>`. I have used the technique from the guide here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/forms.html. Here is the sample I am talking about:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="type">Type :</label>
    <select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="order.type" ngControl="type">
        <option *ngFor="#type of types" [value]="type">{{type}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

In my order-details.component I have got an updateOrder() which calls the updateOrder() from myApp.services.

My problem is when I am trying to send the data from the form to the back-end: all the parts with an `<input>` are OK, but not those with `<select>` (it returns the original values, and not the one selected).

Does anyone have encountered this or a similar problem?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Looks like a dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34686855/angular2-access-a-select-event-change-within-the-component

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There is a way to get the value from different options. 
check this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/tD3UeHLVK9nKYoDJa68d?p=preview)

component.html

```
 <select class="form-control" #t (change)="callType(t.value)">
      <option *ngFor="#type of types" [value]="type">{{type}}</option>
    </select>
```

component.ts

```
this.types = [ 'type1', 'type2', 'type3' ];
   this.order = {
      type: 'type1'          
  };  

  callType(value){
    console.log(value);
    this.order.type=value;
  }
```

Answer (score 5):

Been tackling this problem for a few hours.

Checked in the (incomplete) documentation to find an item in the [NgSelectOption](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgSelectOption) page called "ngValue"

Not sure if this is the intended use but it seemed to work fine.

So instead of using

```
[value]="item"
```

Use:

```
[ngValue]="item"
```

Just use ngModel on the select and ngModelChange event if you want to do something when it changes.

Comment: ngValue can refer to an object while value will refer to only a primitive value. For example if "item" in this case was an object, and the options label was `{{item.name}}` you could then do 

`<select size="10" [(ngModel)]="this.selected">`
    `<option *ngFor="let item of items" [ngValue]="item">{{item.Name}}</option>`
`</select>`

in this case this.selected would be an object. If you used just `[value]`, this.selected would be a string called '{object, object}'

Answer (score 1):

In fact I can't reproduce your problem. I created a plunkr with a very simple form with an `input` and a `select`. When I submit the form, I have actual values in the bound object. See this plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/5C3agW7QZfcrdt88QzSh?p=preview.

Feel free to tell me if I didn't correctly understand your problem.

Thierry

Comment: Actually, it seems that you have reproduced my problem in your plunkr: when I try to submit your form, I am getting the correct value within the `<input>`, but whatever the type I choose in the `<select>`, the console log says "type1". Don't you've got the same behavior?
Thanks for the time you have taken to reproduce the problem by the way :)

Comment: Mubashir have solved my problem by now, but thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

If you have static, hard-coded values for the select tag like below:

```
<select #quantity>
  <option value="one">1</option>
  <option value="two">2</option>
  <option value="three">3</option>
  <option value="four">4</option>
  <option value="five">5</option>
</select>
```

You can do the following:

```
@ViewChild('quantity') quantity: ElementRef;

console.log(this.quantity.nativeElement.value);  // will print value of the currently selected option
```