# Get selected value from a drop-down list in Angular

Tags: angular

I am pretty new to Angular and have a requirement where I need to read the selected value from a drop-down list and send the selected value to a component while routing. Can someone tell how do I extract the selected value from the list?

Here's a snippet of the drop-down list:

```
<div class="dropdown-content">
                <a [routerLink]="['/schedulemanagement/autoStartStopVm']">Auto Start</a>
                <a href="#">Auto Shutdown</a>
                <a href="#">Auto Scale</a>
            </div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2: How to get the selected value from different options of a form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34950160/angular-2-how-to-get-the-selected-value-from-different-options-of-a-form)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Here is the solutions for both your questions:

- To get dropdown value.
- To send params through route

**Solution to your first question binding dropdown:**

**Component:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';


@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {

  constructor(private route: Router){ }

  selectedLevel;
  data:Array<Object> = [
      {id: 0, name: "name1"},
      {id: 1, name: "name2"}
  ];

  selected(){
    console.log(this.selectedLevel)
  }
 }
```

HTML:

```
<h1>Drop Down</h1>
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedLevel" (change)="selected()">
    <option *ngFor="let item of data" [ngValue]="item">{{item.name}}</option>
</select>
{{selectedLevel | json}}
```

[**Here is a working DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qdcjdo)

---

**Solution to your second question To send Params to Route:**

**From Component:**

`this.route.navigate(['schedulemanagement/autoStartStopVm/' + data]);`

So, selected function will be,

```
  selected(){
    console.log(this.selectedLevel)
   this.route.navigate(['schedulemanagement/autoStartStopVm/' + data]);
  }
```

**From HTML:**

```
<a [routerLink]="[schedulemanagement/autoStartStopVm/', selectedLevel]">Person</a>
```

Comment: @Debo, you can accept my answer if you find it useful.

Comment: @Kapilsoni, happy to help you. :-)

Comment: gettting error, can't bind to select since it isn't a known property of select. How to solve this?

Comment: issue resolved. I haven't included FormsModule in module.ts, thankyou @Sravan

Answer (score 3):

I believe you are using bootstrap with Angular. Not `<select> </select>`. An easy solution could be onclick of the link.

html:

```
<div class="dropdown-content">
                <a (click)="getSelectedDropdown('1') [routerLink]="['/schedulemanagement/autoStartStopVm']">Auto Start</a>
                <a (click)="getSelectedDropdown('2') href="#">Auto Shutdown</a>
                <a (click)="getSelectedDropdown('3') href="#">Auto Scale</a>
            </div>
```

component.ts:

```
getSelectedDropdown(link) {
        alert(link);    
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,
HTML:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/schedulemanagement/autoStartStopVm']" (click)="testEvent($event)">Test Event Link</a>
```

TS:

```
testEvent(event) {
console.log(event) //check the event object and get your required values.
}
```