# how to get value from dropdown list in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to get a value from dropdown list. but the value doesn't parse from .html to .ts. any help with that, please.

.html file

```
<mat-card>
    <form (submit)="onAddName(nameForm)" #nameForm="ngForm">

        <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
            <mat-label>select one</mat-label>
            <mat-select name="name" id="name">
                <mat-option value="NAME_01">NAME 01</mat-option>
                <mat-option value="NAME_02">NAME 02</mat-option>
                <mat-option value="NAME_03">NAME 03</mat-option>
            </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
    
  </form>
</mat-card>
```

.ts file

```
 onAddName(form: NgForm) {
    if (form.invalid) {
      return;
    }
    this.nameService.addname(
      form.value.name, 
      );
    form.resetForm();
  }
```

in .ts file, I've used `form.value.<name-from-html>` to get other form values and they worked. only dropdown list is not working. any idea how to slove this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/56845317/10243797 is this your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put `ngModel`angular attribute to access its value

```
<mat-select name="name" id="name" ngModel>// <--
            <mat-option value="NAME_01">NAME 01</mat-option>
            <mat-option value="NAME_02">NAME 02</mat-option>
            <mat-option value="NAME_03">NAME 03</mat-option>
        </mat-select>
```

Here's the working [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/DXwCk2j9GEZroQ89)

Answer (score 1):

you can check out the link for getting value from the dropdown list while selecting the dropdown list selected item for that we will get the value for the respective item.

[Get selected value from a drop-down list in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50135607/get-selected-value-from-a-drop-down-list-in-angular)

Answer (score 0):

Use 2 way binding put ngModel on your select tag

Answer (score -1):

```
    <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
        <mat-label>select one</mat-label>
           <mat-select [(value)]="selected">
            <mat-option value="NAME_01">NAME 01</mat-option>
            <mat-option value="NAME_02">NAME 02</mat-option>
            <mat-option value="NAME_03">NAME 03</mat-option>
        </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
```

.ts file

Comment: Would you care to [edit] your answer and explain the code?