# How can I get value on dropdown in angular?

Tags: html, angular, dropdown

Please I need your help, in this moment I'm in intership. I had never used Angular so it is so difficult. My problem is to have a value on a dropdown. I see how can I have a value on this dropdown for put that value on my file .ts.

```
<tc-form-label>Ajouter les permis de conduire</tc-form-label>
    <tc-form-group>
        <tc-select 
          [placeholder]="'Selectionner les permis de conduire'" 
          [options]="driverLicence" 
          [multiple]="true"
          [filter]="true"
          [allowClear]="true"
          #libelle>
        </tc-select>
    </tc-form-group>
```

Comment: tc-select seems to be a seperate angular component. So you may need to check the code for that. Ideally we can use the [(ngModel)] attribute to set and get values.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2: How to get the selected value from different options of a form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34950160/angular-2-how-to-get-the-selected-value-from-different-options-of-a-form)