# Binding select element to object in Angular

Tags: html, angular

I'd like to bind a select element to a list of objects -- which is easy enough:

```js
@Component({
   selector: 'myApp',
   template: 
      `<h1>My Application</h1>
       <select [(ngModel)]="selectedValue">
          <option *ngFor="#c of countries" value="c.id">{{c.name}}</option>
       </select>`
    })
export class AppComponent{
   countries = [
      {id: 1, name: "United States"},
      {id: 2, name: "Australia"}
      {id: 3, name: "Canada"},
      {id: 4, name: "Brazil"},
      {id: 5, name: "England"}
   ];
   selectedValue = null;
}
```

In this case, it appears that `selectedValue` would be a number -- the id of the selected item.

However, I'd actually like to bind to the country object itself so that `selectedValue` is the object rather than just the id.  I tried changing the value of the option like so:

```
<option *ngFor="#c of countries" value="c">{{c.name}}</option>
```

but this does not seem to work.  It seems to place an object in my `selectedValue` -- but not the object that I'm expecting.  You can [see this in my Plunker example](http://plnkr.co/edit/HGRGv33EFwxDsSnELofk?p=preview).

I also tried binding to the change event so that I could set the object myself based on the selected id; however, it appears that the change event fires before the bound ngModel is updated -- meaning I don't have access to the newly selected value at that point.

Is there a clean way to bind a select element to an object with Angular 2?

Comment: Just realized my Plunk works a little differently in IE vs. Chrome.  Neither one actually works the way I'm wanting, but FYI.

Answer (score 954, accepted):

```html
<h1>My Application</h1>
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedValue">
  <option *ngFor="let c of countries" [ngValue]="c">{{c.name}}</option>
</select>
```

[**StackBlitz example**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7kzu8w)

NOTE: you can use `[ngValue]="c"` instead of `[ngValue]="c.id"` where c is the complete country object.

`[value]="..."` only supports string values
`[ngValue]="..."` supports any type

**update**

If the `value` is an object, the preselected instance needs to be identical with one of the values.

See also the recently added custom comparison https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13268
**available since 4.0.0-beta.7**

```html
<select [compareWith]="compareFn" ...
```

Take care of if you want to access `this` within `compareFn`.

```ts
compareFn = this._compareFn.bind(this);

// or 
// compareFn = (a, b) => this._compareFn(a, b);

_compareFn(a, b) {
   // Handle compare logic (eg check if unique ids are the same)
   return a.id === b.id;
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  Incidentally, the workaround did not work as coded.  In the `updateSelectedValue` function, I had to change `JSON.parse(event)` to `JSON.parse(event.target.value)`

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Could you please also mention that at the answer with the workaround. I guess this is another bug introduced after the answer was posted. There are some pull requests with fixes for `<select>`. Hopefully they'll land soon.

Comment: @Matthijs can you explain why `=c` rather than `=c.id` ? vesion changes or code improvements in source?

Comment: If you use `c.id` you don't need `ngValue`. `ngValue` is to support binding to object instead of binding to string.

Comment: All readers have to double check that they use `ngValue` and not just `value`, even if the select displays the correct text.

Comment: Can you make it work  if the selected item is the second in the list  when the page is loaded?

Comment: Tried it but this does seem to data-bind only from Dropdown to model. If entering the page with model already set the dropdown is not set accordingly...

Comment: @Strinder a frequent mistake is to use another object instance for `selectedValue` than for `c` of (the default item). A different object even with the same properties and values doesn't work, it has to be the same object instance.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Yeah. Already thought of thought. So there's no easy way to sync directly with model and a list of values? = always via onChange?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your last comment.

Comment: Soon we might be able to compare the ngModel objects by their property using custom comparator function. Just watch this issue: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13268

Comment: Support for a custom comparer function was added a while ago https://github.com/angular/angular/commit/f89d004c519fd1645b9f94ff40cd740ad3658360

Comment: if above example is not working, try adding name attribute to select. i.e <select [(ngModel)]="selectedValue" name="test">

Comment: Could someone explain what the comparator does? Calls a callback?

Comment: @TonySamperi `compareFn` is a reference to a function that is called by Angular (if provided) to do custom comparison, for example compare the `id` property of two values not if they are identical object instances (Angular default)

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer so basically it's like the ng-change of AngularJS

Comment: @TonySamperi I don't know AngularJS, but I doubt that is similar. `compareFn` is used to compare `selectedValue` with `countries` to determine which item should be rendered as selected.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer In AngularJS you have `...ng-change="myCallback(selectedValue)" ` which in angular 5 becomes `...
 (change)="myCallback(selectedValue)" ...`. From what I see the compare only wants the name of the function and automatically passes the ngModel and the ngValue of the selected...I seriously don't understand why I would need this...I mean, it could be easily achieved by using (change)...

Comment: @TonySamperi Ok, I now get what `ng-change` does, but `[compareWith]="compareFn"` is something entirely different. It's about to determine if two objects are equal or not and how to do the comparison.

Comment: why can't I find any documentation of `[compareWith]` in [https://angular.io/docs](https://angular.io/docs) ?

Comment: It's always easy once you know it ;-) but https://angular.io/api/forms/NgSelectOption#description contains a link https://angular.io/api/forms/SelectControlValueAccessor with good docs.

Comment: `[ngValue]` instead of `[value]` was the key for me. Thanks.

Comment: You can also make use of Template variable. Pass it inside the change event and then you can get the value which you have set in Select.

Comment: Link to the official documentation: https://angular.io/api/forms/NgSelectOption

Comment: This saved me since I added the `ngModel` inside `option` tag instead of adding it once in the `select` tag, so keep an eye out for it.

Comment: [ngValue] instead of [value] was the key for me aswell!

Answer (score 56):

This could help:

```html
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedValue">
  <option *ngFor="#c of countries" [value]="c.id">{{c.name}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I've used [value] instead of [ngValue]. It's not the same. This worked for me

Comment: Error on '#' in angular 4

Comment: Use `let` instead of `#` @sea-kg

Comment: This answer doesn't get the selected value

Answer (score 23):

You can do this too without the need to use `[(ngModel)]` in your `<select>` tag

Declare a variable in your ts file

`toStr = JSON.stringify;`

and in you template do this

```
 <option *ngFor="let v of values;" [value]="toStr(v)">
      {{v}}
 </option>
```

and then use

```
let value=JSON.parse(event.target.value)
```

to parse the string back into a valid JavaScript object

Comment: This indeed is doable, but on large objects will become a pain. Also, Angular's underline capability of change detection is something to be thought of. Outputting information as json, easily parsable by bots, adds to performance hauls. Using Angular's change detection hides (encapsulates) the logic of the data, and assures you of your needed information. @Günter Zöchbauer answer is the way to do it in Angular. :)

Comment: Helped me where I had a single list and changing one value should not update the next so it helped using this as a hack without the use of ngmodel,Thanks :)

Comment: This works for plain JavaScript objects but note for instances of a class you'd lose all the methods on it.

Answer (score 20):

It worked for me:

***Template HTML:***

I added `(ngModelChange)="selectChange($event)"` to my `select`.

```
<div>
  <label for="myListOptions">My List Options</label>
  <select (ngModelChange)="selectChange($event)" [(ngModel)]=model.myListOptions.id >
    <option *ngFor="let oneOption of listOptions" [ngValue]="oneOption.id">{{oneOption.name}}</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

***On component.ts:***

```
  listOptions = [
    { id: 0, name: "Perfect" },
    { id: 1, name: "Low" },
    { id: 2, name: "Minor" },
    { id: 3, name: "High" },
  ];
```

***An you need add to `component.ts` this function:***

```
  selectChange( $event) {
    //In my case $event come with a id value
    this.model.myListOptions = this.listOptions[$event];
  }
```

Note: 
I try with `[select]="oneOption.id==model.myListOptions.id"` and not work.

**============= Another ways can be: =========**

***Template HTML:***

I added `[compareWith]="compareByOptionId` to my `select`.

```
<div>
  <label for="myListOptions">My List Options</label>
  <select [(ngModel)]=model.myListOptions [compareWith]="compareByOptionId">
    <option *ngFor="let oneOption of listOptions" [ngValue]="oneOption">{{oneOption.name}}</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

***On component.ts:***

```
  listOptions = [
    { id: 0, name: "Perfect" },
    { id: 1, name: "Low" },
    { id: 2, name: "Minor" },
    { id: 3, name: "High" },
  ];
```

***An you need add to `component.ts` this function:***

```
 /* Return true or false if it is the selected */
 compareByOptionId(idFist, idSecond) {
    return idFist && idSecond && idFist.id == idSecond.id;
 }
```

Comment: This is good if you also want to handle the change event to do something extra (like inform a change callback). Though in that case, you only need to put `[ngModel]` and then set your model manually in your custom change callback defined in `(ngModelChange)`.

Answer (score 15):

Just in case someone is looking to do the same using Reactive Forms:

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <select formControlName="country">
    <option *ngFor="let country of countries" [ngValue]="country">{{country.name}}</option>
  </select>
  <p>Selected Country: {{country?.name}}</p>
</form>
```

Check the working example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ibmdtl)

Comment: this.form.get("country").value.Id

Answer (score 8):

In `app.component.html`:

```html
<select type="number" [(ngModel)]="selectedLevel">
  <option *ngFor="let level of levels" [ngValue]="level">{{level.name}}</option>
</select>
```

And `app.component.ts`:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  levelNum:number;
  levels:Array<Object> = [
      {num: 0, name: "AA"},
      {num: 1, name: "BB"}
  ];

  toNumber(){
    this.levelNum = +this.levelNum;
    console.log(this.levelNum);
  }

  selectedLevel = this.levels[0];

  selectedLevelCustomCompare = {num: 1, name: "BB"}

  compareFn(a, b) {
    console.log(a, b, a && b && a.num == b.num);
    return a && b && a.num == b.num;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

For me its working like this, you can console `event.target.value`.

```
<select (change) = "ChangeValue($event)" (ngModel)="opt">   
    <option *ngFor=" let opt of titleArr" [value]="opt"></option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 5):

The key is to use a two way binding in the `select` via `[(ngModel)]` and use `[ngValue]` in each `option`.

You can even have a default null option and it works with Angular 12.

```html
<select name="typeFather" [(ngModel)]="selectedType">
  <option [ngValue]="null">Select a type</option>
  <option *ngFor="let type of types" [ngValue]="type">{{type.title}}</option>
</select>
```

That approach is always going to work, however if you have a dynamic list, make sure you load it before the model.

Answer (score 4):

You Can Select the Id using a Function

```
<option *ngFor="#c of countries" (change)="onchange(c.id)">{{c.name}}</option>
```

Comment: (change) function does not fire any events for this tag but works on <select>, <textarea> and <input>

Comment: In this case we don`t need to fire any event here he needed to catch the Id of the looped list in case you need the event you need to add the (Change) event to the  select element as follows (Change)="myFunction($event)"

Comment: You can find your Value in event.target.value

Comment: And also you need to add whatever the object you want in the Options element as follows 
<option *ngFor="loopObject of loopList"  [value]="loopObject"> {{loopObject.viewProperty}} </option>

Comment: it didn't work. On the option tag but started working when I used it in the <select> tag

Answer (score 4):

Create another getter for selected item

```
<form [formGroup]="countryForm">
  <select formControlName="country">
    <option *ngFor="let c of countries" [value]="c.id">{{c.name}}</option>
  </select>

  <p>Selected Country: {{selectedCountry?.name}}</p>
</form>
```

In ts :

```
get selectedCountry(){
  let countryId = this.countryForm.controls.country.value;
  let selected = this.countries.find(c=> c.id == countryId);
  return selected;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Also, if nothing else from given solutions doesn't work, check if you imported "FormsModule" inside of "AppModule", that was a key for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can get selected value also with help of click() by passing the selected value through the function

```
<md-select placeholder="Select Categorie"  
    name="Select Categorie" >
  <md-option *ngFor="let list of categ" [value]="list.value" (click)="sub_cat(list.category_id)" >
    {{ list.category }}
  </md-option>
</md-select>
```

Answer (score 1):

use this way also..

```
<h1>My Application</h1>
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedValue">
     <option *ngFor="let c of countries" value="{{c.id}}">{{c.name}}</option>
 </select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Attention Angular 2+ users:
for some reason, [value] does not work on  elements. use [ngModel] instead.

```
<select [ngModel]="selectedCountry">
    <option *ngFor="let country of countries" [value]="country">{{country.name}}</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tested on Angular 11. I need an extra object 'typeSelected'. Pay attention I'm not using *[(ngValue)]* as other answers do:

```html
<mat-select formControlName="type" [(value)]="typeSelected" 
            [compareWith]="typeComparation">
  <mat-option *ngFor="let myType of allSurveysTypes" [value]="myType">
    {{myType.title}}
  </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

```
//Declaration.
typeSelected: SurveyType;
...

//Assigning variable 'type' of object 'survey' to 'typeSelected'.
this.typeSelected = survey?.type;
...

    
//Function to compare SurveyType objects.
typeComparation = ( option, value ) =>  {
  if (option && value) {
    return option.id === value.id;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

This code is very simple:

```html
<select class="form-control" id="marasemaat" [(ngModel)]="fullNamePresentor" 
        [formControl]="stateControl" (change)="onSelect($event.target.value)">
  <option *ngFor="let char of programInfo1;let i = index;" 
          onclick="currentSlide(9,false)" 
          value={{char.id}}>{{char.title + " "}}  ----> {{char.name + " "+ char.family }} ---- > {{(char.time.split('T', 2)[1]).split(':',2)}}</option>
</select>
```