# Select as obj in angular2

Tags: angular

I am having issue with select tag and angular2.

I have the following code:

```
     <select id="user" required 
            ngControl="user">
        <option value="" disabled selected>PM</option>
        <option *ngFor="#user of users" [value]="user">{{user.username}}</option>
    </select>
```

where:

```
this.users = [{username: "example", id: 1},{username: "example2", id: 2}]
```

Which should assign to the control `user` choosen object user from users. However, when I add

```
(event)="log()"
```

where `log(){console.log(this.userForm.controls.user.value)`

which gives me:

```
[object Object]
```

instead of:

```
{username: "example",id:1}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't supported right now. For more details you can have a look at this question and the @Günter's answer:

- [Binding select element to object in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35945001/binding-select-element-to-object-in-angular-2/35945293#35945293)