# How can i property bind each object of a for loop to the respective dom element?

Tags: angular

I would like to have something similar to this:

```html
<select>
  <option [bound]="items[i]" *ngFor="let item of items; #i = index">{{item}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: What's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I now use:

```html
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedItem">
  <option [ngValue]="item" *ngFor="let item of items">{{item}}</option>
</select>
```

You can use:

```html
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedItem" (ngModelChange)="onItemSelected(selectedItem)">
  <option [ngValue]="item" *ngFor="let item of items">{{item}}</option>
</select>
```

to detect changes.

`[ngValue]` allows to bind complex objects, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35945293/1374578).

Answer (score 0):

I think you should bind `item` or `i` to `[value]`. Also `#` is [prohibited](https://johnpapa.net/angular-2-ngfor/). and you're lacking of `[(ngModel)]` on your `<select>`.

Take a look at Forms in angular docs, especially here: [Add Powers with *ngFor](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/forms.html#!#add-powers-with-ngfor-).

Answer (score 0):

I Would use something like this:

```html
<select [(ngModel)]="currValue" >
    <option *ngFor="let item of items" [value]="item.value"> {{ item.name }} </option>
</select>
```

With items being an array of objects(value, name).