# Angular 2: How to handle *ngif in option select

Tags: angular

How to can i use *ngif for set a specific default selected option?

I need reload data from database for editing, when i retrieve data i need set the default value of option in base a stored value.

I have this:

```
<select class="form-control" id="deviceModel">
        <option value="">Select a category</option>
        <option *ngFor='let element of category'*ngIf="{{element}}==={{nameDevice}}" value="{{element}}">{{element}}</option>    
    </select>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

ngIf is for structural manipulation, basically whether something is in the DOM, or removed. If you want to bind to the selected property, you could use:

```
<select class="form-control" id="deviceModel">
    <option value="">Select a category</option>
    <option *ngFor='let element of category' [selected]="element === nameDevice" [value]="element">{{element}}</option>    
</select>
```

From https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/SelectControlValueAccessor-directive.html:

> If your option values are simple strings, you can bind to the normal
>   value property on the option. If your option values happen to be
>   objects (and you'd like to save the selection in your form as an
>   object), use ngValue instead.

If you want to use `ngModel` binding, have a look at [Binding select element to object in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35945001/binding-select-element-to-object-in-angular-2)

Note that when using property binding, you don't/shouldn't use string interpolation

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend you to do it in the ts or js file depends on you are using typescript or javascript.

I assume when you load data from the database by sending an ajax request to the API? Use ngModel to bind the data (selectedValue in this case) in template

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedValue">
  <option *ngFor="let c of category" [ngValue]="c">{{c.name}}</option>
</select>
```

and set

```
this.selectedValue = response.value;
```

in the call back function.

Answer (score 3):

`<select class="form-control">
     <option *ngFor="let area of areaData" value="{{area.id}}" 
        [selected]="area.id == userData.area_id">
        {{area.area_name}} ({{area.area_pin}})
     </option>
 </select>`

Use `[selected]` for dynamic selection field in Angular 4.

Answer (score 0):

```
<select class="select1 minimal" [(ngModel)]="A.SkipTo">
 <option *ngFor="let B of Logic" [selected]="B.Question_text == A.SkipTo">{{B.Question_text}}</option> 
</select>
```