# Unable to select value in option (Angular dropdown list.)

Tags: angular, select, html-select

I have searched far and wide. What I got from [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40797296/angular-2-how-to-handle-ngif-in-option-select/40797644) is that I need to use `[selected]` if I want to select a particular option.

It does not seem to be working. Why?
Here is what I have:

```
<ngx-datatable-column name="status" prop="operationStatus" [flexGrow]="1">
    <ng-template let-value="value2" let-row="row" let-rowIndex="rowIndex" gx-datatable-cell-template>
          <select class="geraeteStatus" [(ngModel)]="selectableGerateStatus">
             <option *ngFor="let e of selectableGerateStatus" [ngValue]="e" 
                 [selected]="e.id === value2">
                {{e.id}}
             </option>
          </select>
   </ng-template>
</ngx-datatable-column>
```

I am sure that the value of `e.id` equals that of `value2` at least once per iteration. However it just does not work.
Actually I can put whatever I wish (e.id === 2, or even 'true') into `[selected]` it does not have any effect. 
I have no idea what I am missing. Any answer is highly appreciated.

Comment: if you're using [(ngModel)] you must NOT use [selected]. The problem is that you're using [ngValue]="e". So, the variable "selectableGenerateStatus", is an object -really you need that it's was the same object. Use [ngValue]="e.id" to work

Comment: OK, I got it. I removed 'selected'. I changed to the following:  <option *ngFor="let e of selectableGerateStatus" [ngValue]="e.id">  {{e.label}}</option> . But it still does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I present how I solved the problem. Note that I am quite new to angular, and my approach might be rudimentary. I also want to give credit to @Eliseo who highlighted the fact that **ngModel and selected must not be used together**. That's whay I got rid of the former and used selected only:

component.html

```
 <select class="geraeteStatus" (change)="changeGaerateStatus($event, rowIndex)">
          <option *ngFor="let e of selectableGerateStatus" [selected]="value == e.id">
               {{e.label}}
            </option>
 </select>
```

and the .ts file:

```
    this.selectableGerateStatus = [
  {
    id: 0,
    label: BaseDataComponent.NEW
  }, {
    id: 1,
    label: BaseDataComponent.ACTIVE
  }, {
    id: 2,
    label: BaseDataComponent.DEINSTALLED
  }
]
```

It solved my problem, but it might not be the best approach. Feel free to comment.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use **`[selected]`** in your options

just do some changes like below

> **Component.html**

```
<select class="geraeteStatus" (change)="onChange($event)" [(ngModel)]="selectedStatus">
   <option *ngFor="let e of selectableGerateStatus" [ngValue]="e.id">
     {{e.id}}
   </option>
</select>
```

but here you need to match `ngValue` with your **`ngModel`** then only it will be selected.

> **Component.ts**

```
selectedStatus: string;

onChange(status: string) {
   this.selectedStatus = status;
}
```

For more info about select options [check here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39501595/angular-2-select-option-dropdown-how-to-get-the-value-on-change-so-it-can-be)

Comment: thanks gnaesh045.Unfortunately it still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Bind the option with value instead of ngValue as below.

```
<select class="my-status" [(ngModel)]="myModel.status">
         <option [ngValue]="null" selected disabled> Select Status </option>
         <option *ngFor="let e of selectableGerateStatus" [value]="e">
            {{e.id}}
         </option>
</select>
```