# Angular 2 How to bind selected id in Dropdownlist with model?

Tags: angular, drop-down-menu

I want to call the function when some value of Dropdownlist is selected and that function will use the selected value's id. How could i bind the selected value's id to model? I can load data to the dropdownlist.

```
<select>
  <option *ngFor="let category of categorylist" >
             {{ category.Description }}</option>
                     </select>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2 way binding in angular2 can be customized and we can call upon our own function. Just bind the id to the `ngValue` and have that value go on the `DropdownChange` event.

**HTML:**

```
<select [ngModel]="selectedValue" (ngModelChange)="onDropdownChange($event)" class="form-control">
        <option *ngFor="let category of categorylist" [ngValue]="category.id">{{category.Description}}</option>
     </select>
```

**COMPONENT:**

```
onDropdownChange(e){
  console.log(e)//you will get the id  
  this.selectedValue =e //if you want to bind it to your model
}
```

Comment: Thanks your solution worked. I could call function on change event too.

Answer (score 0):

```ts
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedCategory">
  <option *ngFor="let category of categorylist" [ngValue]="category" >
             {{ category.Description }}</option>
                     </select>
```

You read and set the selected option by reading and assigning to `selectedCategory`.

If the value is an object (not a primitive value) then the instance assigned to `selectedCategory` must be the same as in `[ngValue]`. Just another instance with the same properties and values is not enough.

See also [Binding select element to object in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35945001/binding-select-element-to-object-in-angular-2/35945293#35945293)

Comment: I want to bind selected value's id

Comment: That's the easier version. Just use `[value]="category.id"` or `[ngValue]="category.id"`. I just explained the more trickier one and assumed you'll be able to figure out the easier one by yourself.

Comment: I am getting error Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'select'. should i import any other component ?

Comment: You need to add `FormsModule` to in your `@NgModule({imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule], ...})` (for `AppModule`) or `@NgModule({imports: [CommonModule, FormsModule], ...})` for other modules.