# How to solve "of undefined" problem of a service?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rest, api

I am calling service in Angular7 at every dropdown option change. But when I change selected option on dropdown I am getting `getAllByCountryId of undefined` error.

Here is function that calling http service:

```
countryOnChange(countryId: Guid) {
    this.cityService.getAllByCountryId(countryId).subscribe(
      res => {
        if (res.code === ResponseCode.success) {
          res.dataList.map(item => {
            this.cities.push({
              value: item.id.toString(),
              label: item.dataValue
            });
          });

          if (this.formComponent !== undefined) {
            this.formComponent.form.controls['cityId'].patchValue(this.cities);
          }
        }
      },
      err => {
        this.error = true;
      });
  }
```

Here is the HTML code that calling above function on every dropdown option change:

```
<ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'dropdown'" class="col-md-12">
    <ng-select [ngClass]="'ng-select'" [options]="input.options" [formControlName]="input.key" [id]="input.key" (selected)="input.onChange($event.value)"></ng-select>
</ng-container>
```

`input.onChange($event.value)` and `countryOnChange` is connected at the backend.

Here is how to call **countryOnChange** function:

```
const dropdown2 = new InputDropdown({
      key: 'countryId',
      label: '',
      onChange: this.countryOnChange,
      options: this.countries,
      value: '',
      required: true,
      order: 3
    });
```

[Error http://prntscr.com/ovjxe7](http://prntscr.com/ovjxe7)

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: what means "input.onChange($event.value) and countryOnChange is connected at the backend" ?

Comment: I hope you have initialized your service in your component constructor !?

Comment: Yes, I did @Krunal Shah.

Comment: You can try - (ngModelChange)="countryOnChange($event)" in your <ng-select>. Hope it helps.

Comment: "input.onChange($event.value) and countryOnChange is connected at the backend" means **input.onChange** function is calling **countryOnChange** function. @bubbles

Comment: The error should say "Cannot <do something> of undefined". In your case, likely "Cannot read property getAllByCountryId of undefined". Meaning that whatever is *before* that property is undefined thus it doesn't have the said property. In this case `this.cityService` is `undefined`.

Comment: have you created getAllByCountryId function in your service then ?

Comment: Can you check what you have in your **this** variable in  **countryOnChange** method?

Comment: I couldn't use your suggestion @Krunal. Because `ng-select` uses `(selected)` to capture selection events and this is a dynamic form I couldn't call `countryOnChange` function directly.

Comment: I am getting dropdown properties in **this** variable. @robert. How can I call service then?

Comment: That means you have a wrong value in your **this** variable. Can you share how you call `countryOnChange(countryId: Guid)` method?

Comment: Edited my question and added how to call `countryOnChange(countryId: Guid)` method. @robert.

Comment: Try changing this line: `onChange: this.countryOnChange,` to this: `onChange: this.countryOnChange.bind(this),`

Answer (score 0):

I think [ngModel] is needed:

```
  <select [ngModel]="selectedValue" (ngModelChange)="onDropdownChange($event)" 
   class="form-control">
            <option *ngFor="let category of categorylist" [ngValue]="category.id"> 
         {{category.Description}}</option>
   </select>
```

refer to: [Angular 2 How to bind selected id in Dropdownlist with model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40960743/angular-2-how-to-bind-selected-id-in-dropdownlist-with-model)

Answer (score 0):

`getAllByCountryId of undefined` error means you are getting `this.cityService` as undefined. 
Check with which `this` context your function is binding when you are creating the InputDropDown. May be you need to define it like :-

```js
const dropdown2 = new InputDropdown({
      key: 'countryId',
      label: '',
      onChange: this.countryOnChange.bind(this),
      options: this.countries.bind(this),
      value: '',
      required: true,
      order: 3
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Why do you bind `options: this.countries.bind(this),` ?

Comment: If you want to change countries then you can bind otherwise ignore binding countries. Did it worked with countryOnChange ?

Comment: According to the latest comment under the question it did.

Comment: ohh , i didn't checked the comments. Good to know i was helping correctly.

Comment: There is another problem here. Yes, countryOnChange can be captured but this trigger should populate another dropdown(cities) and this dropdown is like country above too. So how to populate another dropdown after countryOnChange triggered. I tried this: `this.formComponent.form.controls['cityId'].patchValue(this.cities);` But didn't work. @robert, @Sanket

Comment: I solved. I used: `((this.formComponent.inputs as InputBase<any>[]).find(i => i.key === 'cityId') as InputDropdown).options = options;`