# Angular 2 - fetch data from local json to populate dropdown

Tags: angular

I have created a Angular 2 service which reads a local json using http (could be rest service call later) and returns an Observable.

```
   @Injectable()
   export class WorkflowDataService {
   constructor(private http: Http) { }
   getProcessTemplates(): Observable<Response> {
       return this.http.get("/assets/jsons/process-templates.json");
   }}
```

the json that is being read looks like this

```
{
"process-templates": [
    {
        "name": "ABC",
        "desc": "ABC"
    },
    {
        "name": "XYZ",
        "desc": "XYZ"
    },
    {
        "name": "PQR",
        "desc": "PQR"
    }
 ]
}
```

My goal is to show the values of name attributes in a dropdown. So, the dropdown should have - ABC, XYZ, PQR.

So in my component, I am calling this service -

```
processTemplates: Observable<Response>; 
ngOnInit( ) {
  this.workflowDataService.getProcessTemplates()
     .subscribe(function(response) {
       this.processTemplates = response.json();
       console.log(this.processTemplates);
     });
}
```

In the console.log, I see the below output

[image: JSON output]

how can I get the output in a format which can be rendered in a drop down

```
<select class="form-control dropdown" (ngModel)="processTemplate" 
                name="processTemplate" id="processTemplate" required>
              <option *ngFor="let processTemplate of processTemplates">
                {{ processTemplate.name }}
              </option>
            </select>
```

Comment: You can map response to json in your service.

`return this.http.get("/assets/jsons/process-templates.json").map(res => res.json());`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your JSON contains an array inside a object, so you need to extract the array from the object `process-templates`. Made some other changes as well, rather use fat arrow syntax instead of `function`, so you don't loose the context `this` :)

```ts
selectedT: any;

getProcessTemplates(): Observable<Response> {
   return this.http.get("/assets/jsons/process-templates.json")
     // extract array from process-templates object
     .map(res => res.json().process-templates) 
}}
```

Then in your component subscribe:

```ts
this.workflowDataService.getProcessTemplates()
  .subscribe(data => {
    this.processTemplates = data;
    console.log(this.processTemplates);
  });
```

And as for your template, do like John said:

```ts
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedTemplate"> 
  <option *ngFor="let processTemplate of processTemplates">{{processTemplate.name}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: can you please help me to solve this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50059278/how-to-bind-api-response-json-to-drop-down-in-angular4

Answer (score 0):

From a similar question: [Binding select element to object in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35945001/binding-select-element-to-object-in-angular-2)

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedTemplate"> // use banana in a box syntax:[()]
  <option *ngFor="let processTemplate of processTemplates" [ngValue]="processTemplate">{{processTemplate.name}}</option>
</select>
```

Also. You have a different scope for (this) inside your init method. Chaning to a lambda function will solve this. And as mention by @AJT_82, extract the object inside your json

```
ngOnInit( ) {
  this.workflowDataService.getProcessTemplates()
     .subscribe(response => { //removed function, added =>
       this.processTemplates = response.json().process-templates; //extract json
       console.log(this.processTemplates);
     });
}
```

Comment: The output printed on the console shows that it is not in a format that can be iterated using *ngFor, that's why I still get the same error - 
Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

Comment: as @AJT_82 mentions in his/her answer, extract the object inside your json: `this.processTemplates = response.json().process-templates`