# How do I link JSON values to a drop-down field in Angular2 using REST API?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I'm working on the front-end side of a web application and would like to receive JSON object data when I click on the drop down values on my HTML page.

Someone please explain to me how this can be done.

Comment: Can you provide some code? Have you already tried something ?

Comment: do you want to have a json object in the ngModel? you can use ngValue for that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 - fetch data from local json to populate dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42969843/angular-2-fetch-data-from-local-json-to-populate-dropdown)

Comment: To be clear, there's no such thing as a "json object" There's an object, and there's a string in JSON format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wish to have an object json saved as a select element's model value you can use it by using **ngValue** on the option elements.

```html
<select [(ngModel)]="selected">
         <option *ngFor="let value of values" [ngValue]="value">{{value.name}}</option>
      </select>|
```

You can see a working example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/LbuPQiHLLi3LcZ8lGwCD?p=preview).

If you want to do something with the value when  a value is selected you can listen on the **ngModelChange** event.

```html
<select [(ngModel)]="selected" (ngModelChange)="handleChange($event)">
         <option *ngFor="let value of values" [ngValue]="value">{{value.name}}</option>
      </select>|
```

And define the method to call in your controller.

```js
export class App {
  name:string;
  selected = null;
  values = [{name:'a'}, {name:'b'}, {name:'c'}]
  history = [];
  constructor() {
    this.name = `Angular! v${VERSION.full}`
  }

  handleChange(value) {
    this.history.push(value);
  }
}
```

A working example can be found [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/1zwksjGmo0gGnnbbfDkr?p=preview).

Comment: I have the HTML code, but need a basic component.ts code and a code for the service.ts class.

Comment: check the examples, I'll add the controller in here too.

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you so much! :)