# Select a default object in angular2

Tags: typescript, angular2-forms

I am trying a select a default value in the dropdown. Here the value is an object instead of a string. With a string, the below approach works fine. I am facing issues when I try with an object.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'awesome-component',
  template: `
    <select [(ngModel)]="selectedModule">
     <option *ngFor="let module of modules" [ngValue]="module">{{module.moduleName}}</option>
   </select>
  `
})
export class AwesomeComponent implements OnInit {

modules: any[];
selectedModule: any = null;

  ngOnInit(){
    this.loadModules();
  }

  loadModules(){
    //load you modules set selectedModule to the on with the
    //id of modInst.modID[0]._id you can either loop or use .filter to find it.
      this.modules = [];
      this.modules.push({moduleName:'Ford',_id:1});
      this.modules.push({moduleName:'Chevy',_id:2});
      this.modules.push({moduleName:'Honda',_id:3});
      this.modules.push({moduleName:'Toyota',_id:4});

      this.selectedModule = {moduleName:'Toyota',_id:4};
    }
}
```

Comment: Bind to a property of the object like `[(ngModel)]="selectedModel.moduleName"`.

Comment: In `loadModules()` you just need to use the objects from your collection `this.selectedModule = this.modules.find(module => module._id === 4)`. This `this.selectedModule = {moduleName:'Toyota',_id:4}` defines a new object that is not reference equal to any of the existing objects.

Comment: @AluanHaddad Tried [(ngModel)]="selectedModel.moduleName" . It does not bind.

Comment: you also need to change the binding for `[ngValue]="module"` to `[ngValue]="module.moduleName"` accordingly. Of course you can also bind to `_id`

Comment: @AluanHaddad I am looking to send the entire object on select.

Comment: Nevermind, this already has any answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35945001/binding-select-element-to-object-in-angular-2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Binding select element to object in Angular 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35945001/binding-select-element-to-object-in-angular-2)

Comment: @AluanHaddad This question is not related to setting objects on select. The problem stated here is that when an object is set to ngValue the default value is not getting selected based on the object passed

Comment: But it says in that answer exactly why. It is unsatisfying, but true. It works for Objects only when they match referencially (point to the same Object). There should be support for setting a custom converter but otherwise it does not match existing objects. Basically, it just uses default JavaScript equality when what you want is structural equality. Bad API is bad.