# How can I bind data to model from a select that's nested inside an ngFor?

Tags: angular

I'm creating a table where the rows are built out via an ngFor.

In one of the columns I want a select, that also has an ngFor. The problem here, is when I use an ngModel on the select, once I select an option it affects ALL of the other repeated selects. Trying to figure out how to get data from one select.

```
  <tr *ngFor="let data of tableData">
     <td>{{data.SystemName}}</td>
     <td>{{data.StandardName}}</td>
     <td>{{data.DBName}}</td>
     <td>{{data.ResourceName}}</td>
     <td>
       <select class="form-control"> <!--I need ngValue selected for this select-->
         <option value="" selected disabled></option>
         <option [ngValue]="fieldData" *ngFor="let fieldData of uFieldData">{{fieldData.FName}} - {{fieldData.EName}} - {{fieldData.FDataType}}</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
         <select class="form-control">
             <option value="" selected disabled></option>
             <option [ngValue]="mappingTypeData" *ngFor="let mappingTypeData of uMappingTypeData">{{mappingTypeData.Name}}</option>
          </select>
       </td>
       </tr>
```

Comment: what is the model you are trying to bind to?

Comment: @0mpurdy I'm just trying to store the value of the select into the component to use with TS so I can send a post to my database. Maybe I used model wrong, I assumed component is model.

Comment: Then [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35945001/binding-select-element-to-object-in-angular-2) might be what you're looking for

Comment: I'm able to get the value in the option text using (change)="changeField($event.target.value) but $event.target.value only gives me the text, I want to whole item in the ngFor (fieldData)

Comment: Does [this plunker example](https://plnkr.co/edit/ySTI3qja9c3wrBu9s599?p=preview) answer your question?

Comment: @0mpurdy no, both of those only have one ngFor. the rows in my <tr> are made via an ngFor. Inside each row, is a column that has a select with its own ngFor. Therefore, each row has a select (each has the same options from the ngFor in the selects - which is correct). If I use a straight up ngModel, all the selects share the same ngModel and once I change one, all of them then display what was selected in one select

Comment: What about [now that I've updated it](https://plnkr.co/edit/ySTI3qja9c3wrBu9s599?p=preview) to include nesting?

Comment: @0mpurdy you actually got it, if you remove [material] from item[material] you run into the error I'm having. Can you explain this a bit. I assume this works since Item is an object and the [Material] matches the objects in Item?

Comment: Yep I'll post an answer now

Comment: @0mpurdy thanks! I just need to figure out how to use this, since yours is pretty simple. My first ngFor might have anywhere from 5-50 rows depending on the clients data, and I might not touch all the selects. Plus, my selects might have less options than rows so less in the index. I might need to try using the index of each ngFor and use an array or something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JavaScript you can assign properties like `object.property` or `object['property']` ([Read more about this here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp)) you can use the second syntax with Angular's binding inside a nested `*ngFor`

**component**

```js
materials = ['glass','wood','metal'];
colours = ['green','blue','yellow'];
item = {glass: 'green', wood: 'yellow', metal: 'yellow'};
```

**template**

```html
<div *ngFor="let material of materials">
  {{material}}
  <select [(ngModel)]="item[material]">
    <option *ngFor="let colour of colours" [ngValue]="colour">{{colour}}</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Where `item[material]` will resolve to one of the materials like `item['wood']` and assign the `ngModel` based on that.

[Live plunker example](https://plnkr.co/edit/ySTI3qja9c3wrBu9s599?p=preview)

Comment: You're answer helped me get to a solution. I created an empty array. In the parent ngFor I added a "let y = index". In the child ngFor, I used an ngModel  similar to yours [(ngModel)]='selectedField[y]' and now the whole stored without affecting the other selects fields. Thanks!