# On Angular2, what options are available to create a form that re-renders the drowdown list when new data is loaded?

Tags: angular

Basically what I want to achieve is to have a form that has two fields, the first one asks (for example) for the continent with already-loaded options, and the second one is initially empty and asks to select the country, and the list of all countries is loaded after selecting a component from first field.

My program runs on Angular2 framework.

I have tried `ng2-selectize` and `react-jsonschema-form` in order to achieve this, but I can't find a solution so far even though I have tried to read carefully the documentations. Or maybe since I'm a rookie in programming, I'm missing something here? Could anyone list all the packages that you know of that can help solve this task? Would be great if it comes with a documentation detailing the configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is not so complicated and can be done by hand.

```
 <select [(ngModel)]="selectedContinent" (ngModelChange)="onContinentChange()">
   <option *ngFor="let continent of continents" [ngValue]="continent">
   {{ continent }}
   </option>
 </select>
 <select *ngIf="selectedContinent && countries" [(ngModel)]="selectedCountry">
   <option *ngFor="let country of countries" [ngValue]="country">
   {{ country }}
   </option>
 </select>
```

At first step only continent combo-box is visible and after choosing it `onContinentChange()` is fired and Javascript part of component fetches available countries which enable the second part.

For more details about `select` in Angular 2 see https://stackoverflow.com/a/35945293/8490932.

Answer (score 0):

you can use 
***ngIF**.
first have a flag value.then if the continent is selected,then check using ***ngIf**.