# <ng-select> select not working correct

Tags: angular

I am using angular2 and  for drop downs. Whenever a do a search in the drop down and listed items matching criteria highlights the text searched for and on click of which it does not get selected item in the drop down. When you select any other text apart from searched text in the item listed, it gets selected. What causes this behaviour?

Code is as mentioned:

```
<ng-select [items]="tests"
           (data)="updateSelected($event')"
           [active]="selectChannel"
           id="channelList{{tabId}}"
           style="float: left; width: 70%;">
</ng-select>
```

Comment: You're using AngularJS (1.x) in your Angular 2. Check out this question for the proper format of a select with options: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35945001/binding-select-element-to-object-in-angular-2

Comment: You mean to say <ng-select> is compatible with AngularJS(1.x) and not with Angular 2.

Comment: That's correct. Angular (2+) uses a different model.

Comment: But I see in github projects, even angular 4 is using ng-select. https://github.com/basvandenberg/ng-select/

Comment: I mean it's not native to Angular (2+). There are a lot of imitations (either directives or full modules) to recreate the older usage. Have you imported one of these into your project?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<ng-select 
           [items]="tests"
            [(ngModel)]='selected'
           (change)="updateSelected(selected)"
           [active]="selectChannel"
           id="channelList{{tabId}}"
           style="float: left; width: 70%;">
</ng-select>
```

Here, `selected` is a variable you have to declare in the .ts file.