# Angular select default selected select element

Tags: angular

I have following template

```
  <select  [(ngModel)] = "selectedLocation">
    <option *ngFor="let location of allLocationNames" [ngValue]="location">{{location.name}}</option>
  </select>
```

The component has following ngOnInit

```
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() public guest: Guest;
  public allLocationNames: Location[] = []
  public selectedLocation: Location;


  constructor(private apiService: ApiService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.allLocationNames = this.apiService.allLocationNames;
    this.selectedLocation = this.guest.location;
  }
}
```

I would like the default selected element to be the one set in `this.selectedLocation` when the component loads. Right now the selected element in the drop down list seems to be a blank entry.

I am on Angular 5

Comment: this is a expected behavior from Angular, It does not know what will be the value of **selectedLocation** by default, you should give the default value in the beginning !

Comment: I see that your `location` objects have a `name` property. Do they have an `id` property? You could bind to that property instead of binding to the object itself (e.g. `[ngValue]="location.id"` and `[(ngModel)]="selectedLocationId"`). Or you could bind to the name, if you are sure that they are unique.

Comment: initialize **this.selectedLocation** which you used as **ngModel** for 2-way binding in typescript before using it !
Since if you have not initialized it, Angular does not know what to show as the first attribute in dropdown !

Comment: I believe I do initialize it in ngOnInit() ?

Comment: Please post your full code,
As only scenario when dropdown shows empty item in first place is not initializing the ngModel attribute

Comment: @SHOHILSETHIA I edited it

Comment: Hey did either answer help you, or do you need further assistance? :)

Answer (score 0):

Your `guest.location` is a string, whereas each location is an object. If you in this case want to capture the whole object, i.e use `[ngValue]="location"`, you'd want to compare the string value you are getting in `guest.location` and assign the object that matches, to your `selectedLocation`, instead of just having a string value there.

So it can be done like:

```ts
ngOnInit() {
  this.allLocationNames =  this.apiService.allLocationNames;
  this.selectedLocation = 
       this.allLocationNames.find(x => x.name === this.guest.location)
}
```

now you have the whole object in your `selectedLocation`.

**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uuapes?file=app%2Fhello.component.ts)**

Answer (score 0):

check once...

```
    <option value="undefined" disabled selected hidden>select</option>
    <option *ngFor="let example2 of example2s" value="{{example2.value}}">{{example.exampleName}}</option>
</select>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You need to bind to selected property of option element.
Just use  [selected]= "location === selectedLocation" in your options element and your are good to go.

```
<option *ngFor="let location of arrayList" [selected]="location === selectedItem" >{{location.name}}</option>
```

Comment: I tried that. The selected one is still just blank. I do get my correct list of elements in the drop down as before.

Comment: set [ngValue]="location.name"

Comment: Same state than before

Comment: Are you purposefully adding ngModel and ngValue as mine is working good without them.

Comment: How else am I suppose to get the 2-way binding and get the selected value as an object? see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35945001/binding-select-element-to-object-in-angular-2

Comment: Well if you ask me I'm simply using 
`<select>
    <option *ngFor="let location of arrayList" [selected]="location.name === selectedItem">{{location.name}}</option>
  </select>`

Here selectedItem is any of your location.name values.

Comment: This works but how do I retrieve the selected location object (not string) from this?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but are you asking how do you retrieve selected item at any time later?

Comment: Yes. How do I know which location object was selected. I don't see any 2-way/1-way binding in your example

Comment: For two way you should use NgModel 
`<select [(ngModel)]="selectedItem.name">
    <option *ngFor="let location of arrayList" >{{location.name}}</option>
  </select>

Comment: Now we are back to what I had before and what resulted in a blank element being selected. Thanks anyway

Comment: I just edited it **[(ngModel)]="selectedItem.name"**