# Object JSON as value in Angular2

Tags: angular

I show in one `select` one `string` as an `option` and it works. My problem is that I would like to get the whole JSON object as the `value` of this `option` but I get the `string` that I am showing.

My code is the following:

```
    <select *ngIf="car" class="form-control" #oneDoor  (change)="getRecDet(oneDoor.value);"  required >
          <option *ngFor="let oneDoor of car.doors" [ngValue]="oneDoor">{{oneDoor.position}}</option>
    </select>
```

I explain it:
**car and object car**
**car** is the object of one car. The object is like the following:

```
   export class Car {
     name: String;
     doors: [{
       position: String
     }]
   }
```

So I am trying to show just for each `door` the position. That works but I would like that the `value` that I get from the `select` (not the one that I am showing, just the one that I get in my backend) would be the whole object  (`name, doors, position`) but I am just able to get the `String`

I know that `value={{}}` gets only a `string`, so I was trying it with `ngValue` but it keeps happening the same. Any idea?

Comment: this may help you, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35945001/binding-select-element-to-object-in-angular-2. `{{ }}` expects expression and may not recognize object

Comment: I have tried it, but I do not know how should i send that value in (change) --> <select class="form-control"  [(ngModel)]="scenario"  (change)="getIcos(sourceSystemID.value, scenario);">

Answer (score 1):

You should bind it to `ngValue` using the "box" syntax: `[value]`.

```
<select  #coche (change)="getCoches(coche.value);" >
    <option type="text" *ngFor="let coche of coches" [ngValue]="coche">{{coche.nombre}}</option>                       
</select>
```

`value` is only supported for strings. If you want to bind to an object then you should use `ngValue` and bind to it using the "box" notation.

Comment: I have checked it right now. I keeps returning the value of {{coche,nombre}} instead of the object