# get Id and Value from a dropdwn

Tags: angular, typescript, angular4-forms

I have a dropdown like

```
<select [(ngModel)]="car.Marketid" required name="Marketid" id="Marketid" 
 ngModel class="form-control">
    <option [ngValue]="select" disabled [selected]="true">--Select Market--
    </option>
    <option *ngFor="let code of names" value="{{code.marketId}}">
    {{code.marketName}} - {{code.SpecMarketCode}}</option>
</select>
```

In my "save" method in .ts file I need to get Marketid which is selected from this drop-down and MarketName but here   `[(ngModel)]="car.Marketid`"  so I'm getting the only id in my save method in ts file. I need to get marketname also.
How can I get?

update: in my save methode i tried to filter but i am getting Illegal return statement" error in find/filter methode
name => name.marketId this part is compleatly undefined and getting illegal error

```
    save(car: marketmodel) {
    this.submitted = true
    this.marketService.SaveMarketData(car)
        .subscribe(response => 
            const name = this.name.filter(name => name.MMId === 
  car.marketId);//  error here-name => name.marketId this part is compleatly 
                //undefined and getting Illegal return statement error
            this.getmarketdetails();

        });
}
```

Comment: You also could use ngFor"let car of car.Marketid" to parse the whole object

Comment: have you checked this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35945001/binding-select-element-to-object-in-angular

Answer (score 0):

Without changing the view you can lookup the *code* inside the *names* array as follows with the selected `Car.MarketId` model:

```
save() {
  const name = this.names.find(name => name.marketId === this.car.MarketId);

  this.aService.doSomething(name.marketId, name.marketName);
}
```

Comment: hi, i used this one also. but am getting  "Illegal return statement" error in find/filter methode

Comment: name => name.marketId this part is compleatly undefined and getting illegal error

Comment: It's hard to say without knowing the exact contents of your `names` array. Can you reproduce a small example on stackblitz?

Comment: this.names contains:   0
:
SpecMarketCode
:
211
marketId
:
1
marketName
:
"NetherLands"
__proto__
:
Object
1
:
SpecMarketCode
:
232
marketId
:
2
marketName
:
"Switzerland"

Comment: getting "Illegal return statement" error in name.marketId

Comment: Double check your syntax. Make sure your open/closing brackets match `{` `}`

Comment: save(car: marketmodel) {

        this.submitted = true
        this.marketService.SaveMarketData(car)
            .subscribe(response => 
                const name = this.name.filter(name => name.MMId === car.marketId);//error here

                this.getmarketdetails();
     
            });
    }

Comment: this is inside a subscribe methode