# Angular <select> tag multiple value passing

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-forms, angular4-forms

Am working on angular forms where I want to pass values of the select input field in my form.
I have 2 select input field where one works properly when one works fine if I use

```
<option [value]='user.id'></option>
```

but the other one is not working since if I use,

```
<option [value]='user'></option>,
```

where user is an object. I cannot able to parse the value of the particular id of a user (i.e) user.user_id

It returns me an object in the [object] [object] which i try to parse, event.target.value.user.user_id , but am getting undefined error. Can someone help me to solve how to parse the object or how to pass multiple values is [value] field

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Binding select element to object in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35945001/binding-select-element-to-object-in-angular)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `[ngValue]` instead of `[value]` for objects.

See [Binding select element to object in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35945001/binding-select-element-to-object-in-angular) for more information

Comment: am not using ngModal in my entire project I'm using angular form formgroups

Answer (score 1):

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedUsers">
  <option *ngFor="let u of users" [ngValue]="u">{{u.name}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: am not using ngModal in my entire project I'm using angular form formgroups