# Angular - Objects as Select Option Values

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-forms

I have a form with various select boxes which use objects as the value:

`<mat-option [value]="object">`

Which works great when I am creating new records via the form. Now when I am editing records, I run into the problem that the `object` in the `mat-select-option` is not the "same" object that I get from my rest service, so my select boxes have no option selected when editing the record.

Is it possible to tell the select-box widget to match on `object.id` when deciding what option is selected? I think I may need to write a directive to handle this, but maybe this is already possible with Angular or Angular Material libraries, or another existing solution.

To elaborate I have my `foo.component.ts` file:

```
let item = {
    'fruit': { id: 1, 'label': 'Pineapple' },
}

let options = [
    { 'id':1, 'label': 'Pineapple' },
    { 'id':2, 'label': 'Banana' },
    { 'id':3, 'label': 'Papaya' }
]
```

And my `.html` file:

```
<mat-select  placeholder="Fruit" [(ngModel)]="item.fruit">
  <mat-option *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option">{{option.label}}</mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

When the user visits the page, they should see "Pineapple" selected in the `mat-select`. Because the 'pineapple' in the `item.fruit` and the `options` array are not pointing to the same 'pineapple' object - the `mat-select` is empty.

I'd like to see something like:

```
<mat-select          
    placeholder="Fruit" 
    [(ngModel)]="item.fruit" 
    equalityAttr="id"
>
```

Comment: Maybe this can help you:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35945001/binding-select-element-to-object-in-angular/35945293

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Binding select element to object in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35945001/binding-select-element-to-object-in-angular)

Comment: This might help:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35945001/binding-select-element-to-object-in-
angular/35945293

Answer (score 77, accepted):

It is the `[compareWith]` directive. Angular.io is down at the moment, so I will ink to this [medium article](https://netbasal.com/understanding-the-comparefn-input-in-angular-v4-4a401ef4fc4c) for reference.

HTML

```
<mat-select  
    placeholder="Fruit" 
    [(ngModel)]="item.fruit"
    [compareWith]="objectComparisonFunction">

   <mat-option *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option">{{option.label}}</mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

TypeScript

```
  public objectComparisonFunction = function( option, value ) : boolean {
    return option.id === value.id;
  }
```

Comment: Updating in 2021, Was having the same issue, it worked with a little bit of changes ``` [(ngModel)] = "item.fruit" ``` to ``` [(value)] = "item" ``` everything else stays same.

Comment: Hm, I found that `value` might be undefined, so I used `return option.id === value?.id`.