# angular materror check dropdown ngmodel object valid

Tags: angular, string, object, mat-select, mat-error

Good day,

Normally, I will set the drop down value into a string, for example:

```
<mat-form-field>
   <mat-select name="searchReloadType2" placeholder="reload to" required #searchReloadType2="ngModel"
      [(ngModel)]="reloadTypeObjStr" >
      <mat-option [value]="rReloadType.key" *ngFor="let rReloadType of reloadTypeList">{{ rReloadType.label }}
       </mat-option>
   </mat-select>
    <mat-error *ngIf="!searchReloadType2.valid">
        reloadTo is required
    </mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>
```

Where `rReloadType.key` is a `string` value from drop down that set to `reloadTypeObjStr`, and if user click on the drop down list, but didnt select any value, then will show `"reloadTo is required"` under the drop down there.

I wish to have a dropdown list which is set the value to an object instead of a string, for example:

```
     <mat-form-field>
       <mat-select name="searchReloadType" placeholder="reload to" required #searchReloadType="ngModel"
          [(ngModel)]="reloadTypeObj" >
          <mat-option [value]="rReloadType" *ngFor="let rReloadType of reloadTypeList">{{ rReloadType.label }}
           </mat-option>
       </mat-select>
        <mat-error *ngIf="!searchReloadType.valid">
            reloadTo is required
        </mat-error>
      </mat-form-field>
```

where `rReloadType` is an object (instead of `string`) from drop down, and set to `reloadTypeObj`, which is an object. At this point, if user didnt select any value from this drop down, the `reloadTo is required` wont show, the mat-error does not work at this point.

I would like to ask for advise, is there anything I can do for this? Or angular does not support this? I must use string value instead of object value for drop down?

Comment: Have a look on this link [https://stackoverflow.com/a/51989630/8366174](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51989630/8366174). I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Hope you are doin good.

I tried to reproduce your problem, and it is working fine in both the cases, I don't see any problem here.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-form-field-fbtask?file=app%2Fform-field-prefix-suffix-example.html

Also, I would suggest you to use `searchReloadType.errors?.required` inside mat-error, instead of `!searchReloadType.valid`.
So, you can also use `errors?.required`, `errors?.pattern` to check the pattern, `errors?.minlength` and `errors?.maxlength`, etc.
These would be more useful when you are dealing with variety of inputs.

Peace out.

Comment: Is this applicable for angular 8? I tried the same in my workspace, but it does not work.