# Select option dynamically in Angular 6

Tags: angular, select

How can I select an `option` dynamically in Angular 6? The page has many `select`s as shown:

[image: here]

How can I pick the value of an option dynamically if it is equal to `parcela.forma_parcela`?

`parcela.forma_parcela = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6];`

```
<select (change)="setBancoParcela($event.target.value, parcela)" class="input-default" name="forma_pagamento_1" id="forma_pagamento_1">
    <option value="0" [selected]="parcela.forma_parcela == this.value">Banco</option>
    <option value="1" [selected]="parcela.forma_parcela == this.value">BNDES</option>
    <option value="2" [selected]="parcela.forma_parcela == this.value">Boleto</option>
    <option value="3" [selected]="parcela.forma_parcela == this.value">Cartão de Crédito</option>
    <option value="4" [selected]="parcela.forma_parcela == this.value">Cartão de Débito</option>
    <option value="5" [selected]="parcela.forma_parcela == this.value">CH Descontado</option>
    <option value="6" [selected]="parcela.forma_parcela == this.value">Cheque</option>
    <option value="7" [selected]="parcela.forma_parcela == this.value">DDA</option>
    <option value="8" [selected]="parcela.forma_parcela == this.value">Débito Automático</option>
    <option value="9" [selected]="parcela.forma_parcela == this.value">Depósito em C/C</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 8):

Correct Way to make dynamic would be :

```
<select id="select-type-basic" [(ngModel)]="status">
    <option *ngFor="let status_item of status_values">
    {{status_item}}
    </option>
</select>
```

Value Should be avoided inside option since that will set the default value of the 'Select field'. Default Selection should be binded with [(ngModel)] and Options should be declared likewise.

```
status : any = "Completed";
status_values: any = ["In Progress", "Completed", "Closed"];
```

Answer (score 4):

I solved this with: `<option *ngFor="let forma of formas_pagamentos" value="{{forma.value}}" [selected]="forma.value == parcela.forma_parcela">{{forma.nome}}</option>`

Answer (score 0):

You could work with ngModel directive, and export the options from class.

Comment: I'm getting data from DB, and now i need set the correct option value to the "item(parcela)" - In the page have much selects, see the image https://i.stack.imgur.com/4qLcW.png

Comment: @Danillo if you have 1000 select tag, you can use ngModel it's recommended. Look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35945001/binding-select-element-to-object-in-angular

Comment: I solved this with: <option *ngFor="let forma of formas_pagamentos" value="{{forma.value}}" [selected]="forma.value == parcela.forma_parcela">{{forma.nome}}</option>

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 <select
       class="custom-select"
       name="ratings"
       [ngModel]="ratings.OverallRating">
       <option 
        *ngFor="let orc of ratings?.RatingChoices"
         [value]="orc.ratingChoice">
         {{orc.ratingDescription}}
       </option>
    </select>
```