# How i get Angular(TypeScript) Select box's selected text

Tags: angular, angular7

How can I get the selected option text on change function in Angular(TypeScript) ?

Comment: please check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35945001/binding-select-element-to-object-in-angular) I'm sure you will find you're answer there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IF you use default `select html` you can try this:
In youcomponent.html:

```
<select (change)="onChange($event.target.value)">
    <option>Test1</option>
    <option>Test2</option>
</select>
```

In you component.ts:

```
onChange(deviceValue) {
    console.log(deviceValue);
}
```

**EDIT:** To console text insted of value you must do this :

```
<select (change)="onChange($event)">
    <option [value]="1">Test1</option>
    <option [value]="2" >Test2</option>
</select>
```

And in your controller you must use :

```
  onChange(event) {
    console.log(event.target.options[event.target.options.selectedIndex].text);
}
```

Comment: if i use option value this function(onChange) return value. but i need text .

Comment: Read my EDIT paragraph