# I need to print countries based on option selected in array in my code dynamically

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I need simple code help. If I choose any particular letter then corresponding countries should be displayed, in my current position I am not able to do it dynamically.
For example if i choose letter A then countries pertaining to those should be displayed outside the select.

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedOption">
        <option *ngFor="let o of options">
          {{o.letter}}
        </option>
      </select>

<p *ngFor="let o of options">Countries are: {{ o.countries }}</p>
```

```
export class AppComponent {
  selectedOption: string;

  options = [
    { letter: "A", countries: ["Afghanistan", "Albania", "Argentina"] },
    { letter: "B", countries: ["Bangladesh", "Bahamas", "Bahrain"] }
  ]

}
```

If A chosen then Afghanistan Albania ....
If B chosen then ....
If C chosen then .... I should be able to expand array in future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ngValue` instead of using `ngFor`.
You can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35945293/2034794) answer.
[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hnppdl) is the working example.

Your code becomes

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedOption">
  <option *ngFor="let o of options" [ngValue]="o">
    {{o.letter}}
  </option>
</select>

<!-- Just to debug and display selected object -->
{{selectedOption | json}} 

<p>{{selectedOption.countries}}</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
<p *ngFor="let o of options">
 <label *ngIf="o.letter === selectedOption">Countries are: {{ o.countries }}<label>
</p>
```

Comment: Template parse errors:
Can't have multiple template bindings on one element

Comment: I've modified the answer. Could you try that?