# Setting selected value on dropdown list

Tags: angular, dropdown

I have select dropdownlist **Multiple** and assign values from service

service has list of values in array as follows

```
 {roleid:1,roleName:GM}{roleid:2,roleName:SM}roleid:3,roleName:AM}
```

I want to assign values to dropdownlist based on the id I get. (I may get more than one role id in the service, so based on role id received from service it should be selected in the dropdown)

[image]

Comment: Please make sure to add a minimal verifiable code snippet for others to take a look and understand your problem. For more details on how to create [mcve]

Comment: Hey @nircraft, it appears that OP has been active on StackOverflow for about 5 years, so there’s no need to welcome OP.

Comment: @Edric, in that case he should not need a reminder on how to add a [mcve]

Comment: I think this is what you're looking for.  [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35945001/binding-select-element-to-object-in-angular)