# Using ngModel, ngFor with Angular dropDownList

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, ngfor, angular-ngmodel, ngmodel

I have built these two dropDown Lists:
[image]

Using this html code:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <select  name="dropDownList1" class="form-control form-control-sm">
  <option *ngFor="let s of list_of_Values;"  id="field_status" name="field_status"   >{{s}}</option>
</select>
<select  name="dropDownList2" class="form-control form-control-sm">
  <option *ngFor="let s of list_of_Values;"  id="field_status" name="field_status"   >{{s}}</option>
</select>
</div>
```

And this typescript code:

```
list_of_Values:string[]=['value1','value2','value3','value4']
  list_of_Chosen_Values:string[]=['chosenValueOfList1','chosenValueOfList2']
```

What I want to do is use

> ngModel

inside the option tag:

```
  <option *ngFor="let s of list_of_Values;"  id="field_status" name="field_status"   >{{s}}</option>
```

To bind the values of :

```
  list_of_Chosen_Values:string[]=['chosenValueOfList1','chosenValueOfList2']
```

To the chosen values by the user in the two lists.
Is this even doable?

Comment: you can not use ngModel in option tag.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35945293/2626905 I think this will help

Comment: @KapilThakkar what would you advise me to do then?

Comment: @RahulRaveendran Okay will check it out thanks

Comment: stackoverflow.com/a/35945293/2626905 please refer above comment URL

Comment: can you make stackblits