# Angular dropdown not showing default on load

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, dropdown

I'm having a really strange issue with Angular forms.
So basically, I have a form that includes a custom select with 3 options.
`<div class="form-group">
   <label class="form-label" for="custom-select">Type of Map:</label>
       <select class="custom-select" ngModel #mapType="ngModel" name="mapType" required>
           <option *ngFor="let m of mapTypes" value="{{m.value}}">{{m.name}}</option>
       </select>
 </div>`

Now, in theory this should load the data from this array:

```
mapTypes = [{value:1, name:'Draw All'}, {value:2, name: 'Draw Movements (Display Most Recent)'}, {value:3, name: 'Draw Movements (Display All)'}];
```

And it successfully does. The only problem is on page load it looks like this:
[image: dropdownOnLoad]

But, when I click on it I get all of the options (and the values do successfully pass when the form is submitted)
[image: dropdownWhenClicked]

So, my question is, why is this happening and how can I fix it? The options are loading in correctly and the first option is selected as default (which is what I want). Yet it won't show written into the box when the page is loaded. It's weird because I have another dropdown that works just like this (actually more extensive) and it works perfectly fine.

Comment: Review this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/49559488/2153237

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to bind the `ngModel` to a local variable and init this with your desired value.

`[(ngModel)]="selected"`

E.g.:

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label class="form-label" for="custom-select">Type of Map:</label>
       <select class="custom-select" [(ngModel)]="selected" name="mapType" required >
           <option *ngFor="let m of mapTypes" value="{{m.value}}" >{{m.name}}</option>
       </select>
 </div>
```

Component:

```
  mapTypes = [{value:1, name:'Draw All', selected: true}, {value:2, name: 'Draw Movements (Display Most Recent)'}, {value:3, name: 'Draw Movements (Display All)'}];

  selected = this.mapTypes[0].value;
```

Working [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dtwpuy)

Note: General it is a good idea/ easier to use the [material](https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview) components with Angular or try [ngx-bootstrap](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/dropdowns) if your prefer bootstrap.

Comment: No prob, you can up vote if you like ;-) https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be that you are not initializing the value of `mapType`, that is why it does no show anything and it change when you click. So try to set the initialize `mapType` for example `onInit` method.