# Update value in select depending from other field in Angular 8

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angular, typescript

I'm trying to update the value in select in Angular 8.
I found that I can use:

```
$('#selectSeccion').val("SeccionOption");
```

This select is the next one:

```
<select name="seccion" class="form-control" id = "selectSeccion">
   <option *ngFor="let seccion of seccion" [ngValue]="seccion">{{seccion.seccion}}</option>
</select>
```

jQuery code is not working when I use the select with Angular, only works when select is normal html like the next one:

```
<select class="form-control" id = "prueba">
    <option value = ""></option>
    <option value = "other">other</option>
</select>
```

How can I update the value on the "ng" select?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Binding select element to object in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35945001/binding-select-element-to-object-in-angular)

Comment: Do not use jquery for this. Read through the documentation or follow the tour of heroes tutorial so you better understand the basics of angular.

Comment: @Igor I'm not an expert using Angular, probably binding is the answer, however, the answer you pointed is not updating the select, it updates a value based on changes in select but select is updated manually, thanks anyways

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend using jQuery along with Angular.
you can read more about it here: http://www.learnangularjs.net/using-jquery-with-angular.php

The simplest way

component.html:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectModel" (change)="selectionChange()">
    <option [value]="seccion" *ngFor="let seccion of seccions"> {{seccion}}</option>
</select>
```

component.ts:

```
selectionChange() {
    console.log(this.selectModel)
}
```

changing the selectModel parameter will trigger the select to change as well.

Comment: The value in select is updated from another place, I have to updated when a (wheel) method detects a change in another field therefore I can't do it in (change). It should work in the next way: I choose initially an option manually, I scroll my main option (it deletes the value in select) and when I scroll back I'd like to see the option in select I chose manually before the first scroll. The value in select should appear and disappear when I scroll over the main option. Thanks!

Comment: you can bind a wheel event that changes the selectModel parameter

Answer (score 0):

Based on previous recommendation I can updated using Angular, which always was the best way by the way. No jQuery. I have to change my select to the next one

```
<select name="seccion" class="form-control" id = "selectSeccion" [(ngModel)]="value" #ctrl="ngModel">
    <option *ngFor="let seccion of seccion" >{{seccion.seccion}}</option>
</select>
```

Adding this on select tag > [(ngModel)]="value" #ctrl="ngModel" and updating the ts file with this lines:
value : string = '';

```
updatingFunction(){ this.value = "SeccionUpdated"; }
```

I left it if there someone needs it