# *ngFor unable to send property value on change to component

Tags: angular

I am trying to send the select value to the javascript, however I am receiving "undefined".

Example:

```
this._foos = [
{Name:'Foo1', Value: 1},
{Name:'Foo2', Value: 2},
{Name:'Foo3', Value: 3},
{Name:'Foo4', Value: 4}
]
```

I am using *ngFor to display a dropdownlist options.

I would now like to send the Value to the component, however I am unable to figure out how.

Html:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="foo" name="foo" class="form-control" (change)="selectFoo(foo.Value)">
 <option *ngFor="let foo of _foos">{{foo.Name}}</option>
</select>
```

Js:

I have tried the following using the (change) event:

```
 selectFoo(fooVal: any) { // any - is replaced by actual Object type in actual code
        // get supp obj from list
        console.log(fooVal); // it is undefined
    }
```

Comment: is this a duplicae? did you checked [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34686855/angular2-access-a-select-event-change-within-the-component)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to bind a value to the `[value]` property binding

```
<select [(ngModel)]="fooValue" name="foo" class="form-control" (change)="selectFoo(fooValue)">
 <option *ngFor="let foo of _foos" [value]="foo.Name" >{{foo.Name}}</option>
</select>
```

[Demo](https://angular-un2fxo.stackblitz.io)

Comment: thanks, it works. can you elaborate a little more as to why I need to do that? I thought the ngModel was binding it already

Answer (score 0):

you are printing the 'foo' object but you are passing the 'fooVal' parameter.

```
console.log(fooVal);
```

will work fine